# Update a Column in All Rows with Different Values from an expression based on a parameter from another Column in the Current Row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Please, I had recently changed my DB from MS Access To SQL server Express, Access is a wonderful small scale DB for a SINGLE user that have a very simple VBA Functionality which I missed in SQL server!
In My Old Access DB I have [Account] table with a Sub Procedure that Update a field in All Rows in a table with the result of this Expression:

```
[SortOrder] = [AccountNumber] * (10 ^ (Len(MaximumAccountNumber) - Len([AccountNumber])))


where MaximumAccountNumber is a Variable represent the Max AccountNumber in the table.
```

I was searching for a solution for many days but no one example can give me an idea for how to use a Value from a column in the SAME Row to Calculate the result for another Column in that Row and so on for All the Rows in the table as if in the Following VBA code:

```
Do while Not rst.EOF
  rst.Edit
  rst![Field1] = rst![Field2] * ( 10 ^ ( (Len(MaximumAccountNumber) - Len(rst![Field2]) ) )
  rst.Update
  rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Please How to implement such an Update efficiently In SQL server T-SQL **without using a Cursor** because the Rows Count in the table could **reaches to > 100,000**?

Please, I want to do This by Creating a SP which I Can Fire it (Trigger) after every Insert of a New Account to Re-Calculate the SortOrder of All the Rows in the table as in the Following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SortingOrder] 
@MaxOrder Numeric(38,0) = 0, 
@Digits int = 0,
As
BEGIN
set @MaxOrder = (select MAX([AccNumber]) from Account) 
set @Digits = (select LEN(@MaxOrder)) 
Update dbo.Account 
Set [SortOrder] = (Select ([AccNumber] * (POWER(10 ,(@Digits - 
LEN([AccNumber])))  from [Account] )
END
GO
```

As in This Sample Table [Account]:

```
AccID       AccNumber     SortOrder
-----       ---------     --------- 
 023        23            2300
 054        243           2430
 153        5434          5434
```

But when Insert a new Record, I want the SortOrder to be Updated for All the rows to a Number with the same Numbers Count based on 10 Power(Length of the Max AccNumber) as in the Following:

```
AccID       AccNumber     SortOrder
-----       ---------     --------- 
 023        23            230000000
 054        243           243553000
 153        5434          543400000
 233        432345625     432345625
```

Comment: What does `^` stands for, power? like `2^3=8`? Can you [edit] your question to provide some sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert statements) and desired results?

Comment: Can you add your expected result?

Comment: Dear DineshDB , Yes I add the expected results in the Post, the 2 tables examples before and after inserting a new record.

Comment: @hassaneinissa, Try my answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE Account(AccID INT,AccNumber BIGINT,SortOrder BIGINT)

INSERT INTO Account VALUES(23,23,23)
INSERT INTO Account VALUES(54,254,254)
INSERT INTO Account VALUES(125,25487,25487)
```

**T-SQL Query:**

```
DECLARE @MaxValLen INT

SELECT @MaxValLen = LEN(MAX(AccNumber)) FROM Account

UPDATE Account
SET SortOrder = AccNumber * POWER(10,@MaxValLen - LEN(AccNumber))
```

**Output:**

```
| AccID | AccNumber | SortOrder |
|-------|-----------|-----------|
|    23 |        23 |     23000 |
|    54 |       254 |     25400 |
|   125 |     25487 |     25487 |
```

Comment: Working Correctly.

Comment: @hassaneinissa, You are welcome!!! If you found this answer is correct then Accept the answer. This will help someone in the future.